# windows 2003 server - visualGC in visualVm Not supported for this JVM(jdk 1.7)

Tags: java, visualvm

When I try to see visualGC in visualVm, it says "Not supported for this JVM"
and the soln I found is

```
run jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=tools.policy
```

and when i run this command, i get

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=to
Could not create remote object
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses"
 "write")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermissi
on" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")
```

soln to this issue is [jstatd oracle link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstatd.html), but this link says
 `It is not currently available on the Windows 98 and Windows ME platforms`

I am attempting to connect from local machine to remote server Windows2003
JDK 1.7 is what I used for visualVM and Visual GC

please help!

Comment: Did you also create the appropriate `tools.policy` file?

Comment: yes, done that also. again with help of internet/google/SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was bit different, the reason I am getting 'Not supported for this JVM' is because the app which I want to profile is a windows service, thus the visualGC tab shows 'Not supported for this JVM'. 
What we done is , took the .exe file and run it on console with -run as param, and it ran as normal java app, and thus able to see visualGC tab

The doubt i have is , we did not ran jstatd(my app was running as windows service on windows server 2003), so how come we are able to view the VisualGC, contrary to what I see on the internet and acc what I have written in my question

Comment: You don’t need jstatd for local JVMs and even for network connections there are possibilities to create JMX connections without it. But if your application runs as a service, it usually runs under a different user account. So a normal user can’t connect to it via local JVM discovery for security reasons.